# NEPacketTunnelProvider "source-application mode"

Tags: ios, networkextension

The apple [documentation for the PacketTunnelProvider](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/packet_tunnel_provider) states that it can run in either "source-application mode" or "destination IP mode", but it doesn't mention the "source-application mode" anywhere else nor does it mention how to enable it.

> Packet tunnel providers can run in destination IP mode or source-application mode. The latter is one form of per-app VPN (the other form is an App Proxy Provider).

I'm trying to figure out how to run it in source-application mode. I have found the `.appRules` property of the NEPacketTunnelProvider class but it is a `let` constant and cannot be modified. It seems to be a list of [NEAppRule](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/neapprule) objects, but I'm not even positive that these are what's required or that they would in any way facilitate "source-application mode".

I'm trying to find any documentation or information regarding the "source-application" mode of the NEPacketTunnelProvider.

I wish I had more code to share that I may have tried, but so far all I've found that *might* be relevant is the `.appRules` property of the NEPacketTunnelProvider.

Comment: Notice that this mode is only for devices enrolled via MDM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to find the related documentation. For some reason, it's located on the documentation page for the [NETunnelProviderManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/netunnelprovidermanager) class.